# XMLSchema validation with Catalog.xml file for entity resolving

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

i have a `schema.xsd` which includes and modifies xhtml like this:

```
<xs:redefine schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml11.xsd">
...
</xs:redefine>
```

Now i have written a Validator, which

- reads the schema from xml file
- uses a CatalogManager for resolving entities

it works fine as it does not load any files from the net but rather finds xhtml11.xsd as given in my `catalog.xml` file.

```
public class XmlTemplateValidator implements TemplateValidator
{
    public List<SAXParseException> validate ( String xml ) throws Exception
    {
        Reader input = new StringReader(xml);
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(input);

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        factory.setValidating(true);
        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
        parser.setProperty("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
        reader.setEntityResolver(new CatalogResolver());
        DefaultErrorHandler handler = new DefaultErrorHandler();
        reader.setErrorHandler(handler);
        reader.parse(inputSource);
        return handler.getSaxParseExceptions();
    }

}
```

Now i want exactly the same thing, but i want to give the schema inside my validator (so not let the author say against which schema it should validate, but rather let the validator decide which schema to use.

```
public class NewXmlTemplateValidator implements TemplateValidator
{
    static final String schemaSource    = "schema.xsd";

    public List<SAXParseException> validate ( String xml ) throws Exception
    {
        Reader input = new StringReader(xml);
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        URL schemaUrl = getClass().getResource(schemaSource);
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaUrl);
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        DefaultErrorHandler handler = new DefaultErrorHandler();
        validator.setErrorHandler(handler);
        Source source = new StreamSource(input);
        validator.validate(source);
        return handler.getSaxParseExceptions();
    }
}
```

It works but it does load all xhtml files form the net which takes rather long and is not what i want.

So i want to validate a XML String against a predefined schema with proper entity resolving via a catalog.xml definition.

How can i easily add a CatalogResolver to the second setup?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add an XMLCatalogResolver in the second example like this:

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
URL schemaUrl = getClass().getResource(schemaSource);
String catalog = getClass().getResource("/catalog.xml").getFile();
XMLCatalogResolver resolver = new XMLCatalogResolver(new String[] { catalog });
factory.setResourceResolver(resolver);
```