# How to get all namespaces and URLs to populate xsi:schemaLocation attribute when marshalling a JAXB model

Tags: xml, jaxb, schema

In JAXB output I'm trying to populate the xsi:schemaLocation attribute so it contains complete information for *all* the namespaces and schemas that were used. I am trying to find a better way than hardcoding it!

We have a XML schema that's spread across about fifty files.  Each file defines a type and has its own namespace.  (Not a smart decision I think, but too late to argue that one.)  XJC happily compiles the whole mess and generates classes.  When the output is marshalled all the 50+ namespaces are properly put on the root element.

The problem is that I've been asked to populate the xsi:schemaLocation attribute with *all* the namespaces and associated schema sources.  So instead of just one namespace-URL pair ("my.co.schema.v1 http://my.company.com/schemas/my.co.schema.v1.xsd"), I will need to put 50+ pairs in there.  Sure I can hardcode it but that's wrong.

I'd like to query JAXB about all the sources it used, but that doesn't seem possible. I'm starting to think I have to use a Xerces grammar pool and read all the schemas in again.  Is that the best option?

I added a SCCE below.  Works fine, but as I mentioned, the xsi:schemaLocation attribute is hardcoded and incomplete.

Please help, thanks in advance.

```
package my.xml.generator;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

import my.schema.ComponentType;
import my.schema.ObjectFactory;
import my.schema.ProductType;

/**
 * Builds a JAXB object and serializes to a file.
 * 
 * Many thanks to
 * http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html
 */
public class SimpleXmlBuilder {

public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    if (argv.length != 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Usage: SimpleXmlBuilder output-file-path");

    // Create a trivial component
    ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
    ProductType product = objectFactory.createProductType();
    product.setDeprecated(true);
    // Wrap in a root element
    JAXBElement<ProductType> rootElement = objectFactory
            .createProduct(product);

    // Get JAXB going
    Class<?>[] rootElementClass = { ComponentType.class };
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(rootElementClass);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    // Leave some whitespace for humans
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    // The critical part of the problem!
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION,
            "My.Name.Space.v1" + " "
                    + "http://my.server.com/schemas/My.Name.Space.v1.xsd");

    // Write to the named file
    marshaller.marshal(rootElement, new File(argv[0]));
    System.out.println("Wrote generated XML to " + argv[0]);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Demo Code

You could leverage the `javax.xml.validation` APIs to resolve all the schema locations with an `LSResourceResolver`.

```java
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.*;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        MyLSResourceResolver resourceResolver = new MyLSResourceResolver();
        sf.setResourceResolver(resourceResolver);

        StreamSource rootSchemaSource = new StreamSource("src/forum17992435/schema1.xsd");
        sf.setResourceResolver(resourceResolver);
        Schema schema = sf.newSchema(rootSchemaSource);
    }

    private static class MyLSResourceResolver implements LSResourceResolver {

        @Override
        public LSInput resolveResource(String type, String namespaceURI,
                String publicId, String systemId, String baseURI) {
            System.out.print(namespaceURI);
            System.out.print(" - ");
            System.out.println(systemId);
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

### XML Schemas

**schema1.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema1" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/schema1" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <import namespace="http://www.example.org/schema2" schemaLocation="schema2.xsd"/>

</schema>
```

**schema2.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema2" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/schema2" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <import namespace="http://www.example.org/schema3" schemaLocation="schema3.xsd"/>

</schema>
```

**schema3.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema3" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/schema3" elementFormDefault="qualified">
</schema>
```

### Output

The demo will output the locations of the 2 imported schemas.  You will need to provide the location of the first XML schema.

```
http://www.example.org/schema2 - schema2.xsd
http://www.example.org/schema3 - schema3.xsd
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Blaise for the pointer!  His solution absolutely works, and it confirms I have to do the work of reading in all the schemas again, starting with the root schema.  That info is not available from JAXB artifacts anywhere.

Example code is below, a resource resolver gathers the URI and associated system ID pairs as they are found by the schema factory.  The resolver also uses a real XML catalog file so the schema processor uses locally cached schema files (instead of reading URLs over the net).  Also added  code to validate the JAXB object in memory using the newly loaded  schema.

Solution below requires Java 1.6 only, no 3rd-party libs.  I'm concerned about using a class that's marked "internal" tho.

```
package my.xml.generator;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.util.JAXBSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;

import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSInput;

import my.schema.ObjectFactory;
import my.schema.ProductType;

import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.XMLCatalogResolver;

/**
 * Builds a JAXB object, validates it then serializes it to a file.
 * 
 * Credit to Blaise Doughan for answering questions and these posts:
 * http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html
 * http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/validate-jaxb-object-model-with-xml.html
 *
 * Also helpful:
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364840/xmlschema-validation-with-
 * catalog-xml-file-for-entity-resolving
 */
public class ValidatingXmlBuilder {

/**
 * Hooks in to the system resolver to gather details about schemas.
 */
static class MyXMLCatalogResolver extends XMLCatalogResolver {

    /** List of "URI - SystemID" strings */
    private final List<String> namespaceUrlPairs;

    public MyXMLCatalogResolver(String[] catalogs) {
        super(catalogs);
        namespaceUrlPairs = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    /**
     * Gathers namespace URI and system ID pairs
     */
    @Override
    public LSInput resolveResource(String type, String namespaceURI,
            String publicId, String systemId, String baseURI) {
        String pair = namespaceURI + " " + systemId;
        namespaceUrlPairs.add(pair);
        // System.out.println("Resolver found URI-system ID: " + pair);
        return super.resolveResource(type, namespaceURI, publicId,
                systemId, baseURI);
    }

    /**
     * @return String containing pairs of namespace URI and corresponding
     *         system ID, using a single space as separators
     */
    public String getSchemaLocationPairs() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (String pair : namespaceUrlPairs)
            sb.append(pair + " ");
        return sb.toString().trim();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    if (argv.length != 3)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Usage: ValidatingXmlBuilder schema-file catalog-file output-file");

    // TODO validate existence of files
    String schemaPath = argv[0];
    String catalogPath = argv[1];
    String outputPath = argv[2];

    // Create a schema with a catalog resolver to gather details
    System.out.println("Reading schema from " + schemaPath);
    System.out.println("Reading catalog from " + catalogPath);
    MyXMLCatalogResolver hookedResolver = new MyXMLCatalogResolver(
            new String[] { catalogPath });
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory
            .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    schemaFactory.setResourceResolver(hookedResolver);

    // Read in the schema to gather the info
    Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new File(schemaPath));

    // Create a trivial product and wrap it in root element
    ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
    ProductType product = objectFactory.createProductType();
    product.setSchemaVersion("1.0");
    JAXBElement<ProductType> rootElement = objectFactory
            .createProduct(product);

    // Get JAXB going for a this root element type
    Class<?>[] rootElementClass = { ProductType.class };
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(rootElementClass);

    // Create a validator and check the object
    // TODO: Create custom instance of org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    JAXBSource source = new JAXBSource(jaxbContext, rootElement);
    validator.validate(source);

    // Create and configure marshaller with gathered info
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    // TODO: Fixup URI of root schema, specified here as file
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION,
            hookedResolver.getSchemaLocationPairs());

    // Write to the named file
    marshaller.marshal(rootElement, new File(outputPath));
    System.out.println("Wrote generated XML to " + outputPath);
  }

}
```